# How to run a python script in remote server from Jenkins configuration

Tags: python, jenkins, ssh-keys, ssh-tunnel

Hello everyone ,
         I have a python script called "upgradePreChecks.py" present in the     remote server under "/tmp" location .
         I have a job configured in Jenkins to run that script in server from execute shell .
         Below is the code snippet I am using in execute shell inside Jenkins configuration .

```
   #!/bin/bash
   USER="root"
   HOST="10.32.235.49"
   PASS="shroot12"
   expect -c "
   set timeout 20000
   spawn ssh -r -P 2205 /tmp/upgradePreChecks.py  $USER@$HOST:/tmp/
   expect \"*assword:\"
   send \"shroot12\r\"
   expect eof
   "
```

But I am getting error of invalid syntax .
 Can anyone please suggest where I am doing wrong .
 Thanks in advance .

/Abinash

Comment: no we can't because you didn't write down the exact error and the source code of the python script.

Comment: Provide the console output of this build step to understand what error it is throwing.